# htaccess - better url for the page

Tags: .htaccess

I just like to have created my url better for SEO, it will be in place for such here "**/articles/4/**" so it becomes "**/articles/4/Array-be-better-with-it/**"

right now it looks like this;

```
RewriteRule ^artikler/(\d*)/$ /alt-artikler.php?id_artikler=$1
```

I also try to do it like this;

```
RewriteRule ^artikler/([0-9]+)/?.*$ alt-artikler.php?$1 [L]
```

I do not know how I do this that I have written like this in my url:

**/artikler/4/Array-blive-bedre-til-det/**

Comment: You want `/articles/4/` to become (To go to) `/articles/4/Array-be-better-with-it/`? If so, the URL entered in the browser address bar must be `/articles/4/`, which also will be the only one visible.

Comment: I do not understand just quite what you think?

Comment: OK. When `/articles/4/` is entered in the browser address bar, do you want it to go to `/articles/4/Array-be-better-with-it/`? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: I can not fix it in minutes. htacces file?

Comment: Sure, but it is not clear how do you want to do it. Your question is somewhat different from what you are trying to achieve in .htaccess file.

Comment: What I would like to have been up since it is blabla.com/artikler/4/array / and into that which stand array if I'm doing intervals or. or like that make it appear unnatural then it away so it only too well be blabla.com/artikler/4/array-google-facebook /

hope you understand me now :)

Comment: have found its out of it, that is like this;

RewriteRule ^ articles / (. *) / (. *) / $ / All-artikler.php? Id_artikler = $ 1 = $ 2

but now it is just that the $ 2're doing it like this then some strange resemble characters / Viewing% 20navn% 20THE% 20siden% 20with% 20IT% 20samme /

So 20% must be converted to "-"

Comment: You can translate `%20` to `-` with following rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)%20(.*)$` $1-$2`. Consider also to update your first rule to be like this: `RewriteRule ^articler/([[:digit:]]+)(/.*)?$ /alt-artikler.php?id_articler=$1&alt=$2`